# Windows 7 doesn't see my 2TB partition created in Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, partitioning

I connected a new HDD to my PC, to be used as media storage.

**Device:** WD Green 3TB Drive (WD30EZRX). 
**OS:** Windows XP x32.

I used "Acronis True Image WD Edition". It created 2TB partition with MBR, and ~800Gb unallocated space left. I also have 2nd OS installed - Windows 7 x64. When I load Windows 7 it sees only 800GB unallocated area as an unformatted disk in windows explorer, but it doesn't see my 2tb partition. BIOS sees only 800GB as well.

Question: How can I make my Win7 x64 to see the 2TB partition that is visible in WinXP x32 and created with Acronis?

I guess that the problem is in special MBR that was created with Acronis.

*Note: I cannot re-format the drive cause there are already 500GB media data on it.*

**UPD:** Hard drive is connected vi SATA interface. I also have other older HDD for 160 Gb, which I use for booting the system. While PC is loading I can choose the OS in BIOS. See Disk Manager screens from WinXP and Win7 below.

Windows XP x32 (sorry for Russian locale):

[image: XP]

Windows 7 x64:

[image: Win7]

Comment: How is this drive attached to the system(s)?  Are you dual booting, or is this a USB drive, or is USB dock or something?  It might be interesting to get a screenshot added of what you see in Computer Management\Disk Management for the two systems.

Comment: Zoredache, See my update in the initial post after "UPD:" keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I have no idea what, but I suspect some component on your Windows 7 system doesn't support large drives.